# Semaphore deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, semaphore

So I have a problem using semaphore.
Writing a code where are 4 rooms and some visitors. Each room has a certain cap for the amount  of visitors they can hold. So entering a full room would trigger a wait().
The visitors must not leave a room before they can enter another, so they are always in a room.

```
public class Semaphore {

  private int placesLeft;

  public Semaphore(int placesInRoom) {
    this.placesLeft = placesInRoom;
  }

  public synchronized void acquire(Visitor visitor) {
    Semaphore sem = visitor.getRoom().getSemaphore();

    try {
      while (placesLeft <= 0) {
        this.wait();
    }

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

  sem.release();
  placesLeft--;
}

public synchronized void release() {
  placesLeft++;
  this.notifyAll();
}
```

Deadlock appears when 2 people are trying to enter each other's rooms.
Also for some reason the `placesLeft` count is not coming out right.

So what should I do?

EDIT:

Been busy with something else, reviving the question.
The problem doesnt occure because of rooms get full, lock occures when person1 from room1 wants to enter room2 and the same time person2 from room2 wants to enter room1. As I understant its something to do with synchrozing maybe? They get stuck before release, so release is not called. As i understand one rooms accuire and release cannot be called same time. So basicly room1 semaphore release cannot be called cuz on same time the accuire is called, same for room2? I'm newbie coder and synchronizing is not so clear yet. 
Removing synchronizes from one or another doesnt seem to work (is prolly wrong also).

Comment: Deadlock is a logical result if both rooms are full.

Comment: Your "<= 0" is a symptom of an error.  The value should never be under 0.  So "==" should do.  Why are you passing _room_ into acquire() ?

Comment: Should two visitors be allowed to swap rooms, or is deadlock the preferred outcome in this case?

Comment: @David he has 4 rooms to work with...  I think he can swap, he just has to work for it a little.

Comment: Deadlock is not the prefered outcome here. I want two visitors to be able to swap rooms, atm it causes lock, even tho both rooms have places left.

Comment: If both rooms have free space, visitor-swapping as I described in my answer isn't necessary. My answer is designed to address the problem where two rooms are full and each has a visitor trying to move to the other room.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of implementing your own, how about using [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) which is build into the Java Standard Library?

The `java.util.concurrent` package has a great [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) covering Semaphores and the many other useful synchronization mechanisms which it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock occur when there is a cycle in the dependency graph. When 2 people are trying to enter each other's rooms, this is evidently a cycle, and deadlock is a natural consequence.

However, you want to treat cycles in other way: when cycle occur, people all move along the cycle (there can be more than 2 people exchanging rooms).

So you should first determine if a cycle is formed, and then change visitors' locations.

Answer (score 0):

Add a list of current visitors to `Room` so that you can check in `acquire` for the condition that the incoming visitor is coming from a room that one of this room's occupants is waiting to enter. You'll also need to add the room a visitor is waiting to enter to `Visitor`.

```
Room comingFrom = visitor.getRoom();
while (placesLeft <= 0) {
    for (Visitor waiter : room.getVisitors()) {
        if (waiter.getWaitingForRoom().equals(comingFrom) {
            // swap the visitors without releasing/acquiring any semaphores and return
        }
    }
    this.wait();
}
```

I'm a bit unsure of the logic to check if a visitor is waiting to enter the same room the current visitor is leaving. I can't tell which room `room` represents given the code.

Comment: A list of waiting visitors is a strategy, but doesn't seem germane to the solution.

Comment: You need some way to detect that visitor A in room R is waiting to enter room S while visitor B in room S is waiting to enter room R.

Comment: Well, no.  According to the OP, your scenario can not be resolved.  Visitors must be in a room; they can't be in transit.  Therefore if two rooms are full, visitors can't move between them.  But that's really not his issue - he just has bugs, methinks.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Not a bug, a specification problem.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - "Deadlock appears when 2 people are trying to enter each other's rooms."

Comment: Yes.  And I am saying that's the only logical result, as per @JamesMartin above.  However, looking at the OP's code, I don't think that's his only problem.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - I agree deadlock will happen as it's coded, but I inferred from the comment I quoted that this is not desired and visitors *should* be allowed to swap rooms.

Comment: @David - I posted a suggestion, let's see if we get some clarification.

Comment: If visitors are allowed to swap rooms, doesn't that imply that there is a non-empty room between the rooms?  If so, what happens when that gets full as well?  In what way is a list of waiting visitors different than an extra room of unlimited capacity?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "What should I do?", if you detect a deadlock, move one of the deadlocked Visitors to any room with space.  Then move him to the room he really wants.  This basically allows a swap without violating any of the rules below.

1. Rooms must never contain more than X visitors
2. A Visitor is always in exactly one room
3. Only one Visitor can change rooms at a time (which really is the crux of the problem)

Bear in mind there are about a zillion semaphore locking strategies out there...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Semaphore {
  private final static Object LOCK = new Object();
  private int placesLeft;

  public Semaphore(int placesInRoom) {
    this.placesLeft = placesInRoom;
  }

  public void acquire(Visitor visitor) {
      synchronized (LOCK) {
          Semaphore sem = visitor.getRoom().getSemaphore();

          try {
              while (placesLeft <= 0) {
                  LOCK.wait();
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        sem.release();
        placesLeft--;
    }
}

public void release() {
    synchronized(LOCK) {
        placesLeft++;
        LOCK.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

The old code synchronized on the individual Semaphore instances. It is very hard to prevent deadlocks, because the `acquire()` method of one instance calls `release()` of another instance. The call to `release()` then blocks if another thread is currently executing the `acquire()` method on that other instance. If that second thread finally call `release()` on the first instance, you have a deadlock.

I replaced synchronization on the individual Semaphore instances by synchronization on a single object named `LOCK`. The thread that executes `acquire()` has locked the monitor of `LOCK`. This thread is therefore not blocked when it calls the `release()` method. The `release()` method will thus always terminate. This solves the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks are usually resolved by a hierarchical semaphore system. Typical dead lock looks like

Process A

```
getSemaphore('A');
getSemaphore('B');
```

Process B

```
getSemaphore('B');
getSemaphore('A');
```

Just for all processes to select A before B. This can be accomplished by writing your `getSemaphore` function to enforce the hierarchy with asserts.

For your specific case this doesn't solve the problem very obviously but you can extrapolate from this idea.

Create a migration queue. When a user want to change rooms your function might look like:

```
ChangeRoom(person, from, to)
{
    getSemaphore('room_queue', 3200);
    enqueue(room_queue, Object(person, from, to));
    releaseSemaphore('room_queue');
}
```

The "3200" is a semaphore timeout. If a process gets interrupted after squiring the semaphore it will still deadlock the system. This give a 1 hour timeout. You can set it to a logical value 1 min, 5sec based on your systems stability.
Then have a queue processor that only allows one transfer at a time with a non-blocking semaphore

```
QueueProcessor()
{
    getSemaphore('room_queue', 3200);
    for (transition = dequeue(room_queue))
    {
       if (getNonBlockingSemaphore(transition.to)
       {
          releaseSemaphore(transition.from);
          getSemaphore(transition.to);
       }
       continue;
    }
    releaseSemaphore('room_queue');
    sleep(10);
}
```

The sleep keeps the queue process form overwhelming the processor. Set it to an appropriate check. You can also set up interrupts to pull queue items only when a room has a space opened or a transition is added. This way if a room is full it won't waste time attempting to get in but everyone will have at least one shot to get in immediately.

This forces a transition to obtain the queue semaphore before they can obtain a room semaphore. Setting up a deadlock free hierarchy. A user will never leave the queue if a room is full but it will not deadlock the system.